# Works for GET, not for POST (404 error)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, http-status-code-404, iis-express

I have a WebApi controller `ServicesApiController` in my MVC4 project with a signature like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "sysadmin,Secretary")]
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IEnumerable<Stock> TopRankedStocks(int maxRecords)
{
    // do stuff
    return result;
}
```

My routing for my api controllers looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ServicesApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "ServicesApi", action="Index" }
    );
```

Using IIS Express, if I navigate to `http://localhost:62281/api/ServicesApi/TopRankedStocks?maxRecords=20` in my browser, I get a nice xml list of my data objects.

However, if I call it like so:

```
myHttpClient.BaseAddress = "http://localhost:62281/";
var arguments = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(new[] { KeyValuePair<string, string>("maxRecords", "10") });
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(arguments);
var result = myHttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/ServicesApi/TopRankedStocks", content).Result;
```

...I get a 404 (Not Found) error.

POST operations work in other places in my code.  My config files for the application and IIS Express all allow all verbs.  I have no idea why this is not working.  Can someone clue me in?

I don't know if any of this is relevant information, but I'll post it in case there's some value here:

- Windows 8 64 w/ 4GB RAM
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional Update 2 with Resharper
- IIS Express 8
- .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Try adding `System.Web.Http.HttpPost` after [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]

Comment: @PSL can you clarify?  Add it where?

Comment: After AcceptVerbs add  [System.Web.Http.HttpPost] attribute on top of `public IEnumerable<Stock> TopRankedStocks` method and give it a try.

Comment: @PSL this has no effect.

Comment: Is your `AcceptVerbs` from `System.Web.Mvc` or `System.Web.Http`?

Comment: @PSL, it is `System.Web.Http`.

Comment: Does the `[FromBody]` have any effect if you place it before the parameter?  I know that won't work for GET, but might help to isolate the issue.

Comment: @DavinTryon `[FromBody]` does not appear to be a valid method attribute.  Are you suggesting I decorate my controller with this attribute?

Comment: [FromBody] is a parameter attribute, that's why he said "before the parameter". The main problem here is that POST expects data to be sent - but you do not accept the sent data anywhere in your method singature. Primitive parameters are passed by Uri as default, but using that attribute you say "I want it to be taken from the body". I'm not sure whether this will break passing the paratemer with the GET attribute. You're better off just creating two different methods and use the ActionName attribute.

Comment: @Jeremy - if you want to mark the param as fromBody you do it like that: `public IEnumerable<Stock> TopRankedStocks([FromBody]int maxRecords)` as it's not a method attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a potential issue with this controller method:

The problem is that your argument is of type `int` (primitive type) - as long as you don't mark it as `[FromBody]` the WebApi parameter binding engine will assume that it comes from the url. That explains why GET works; I'm not sure how POST is considered when you don't supply the value in the url.

Still, if you marked maxRecords as FromBody and tried using it with a GET method it would stop working most probably. 
Also, note that in case you wanted to use `form-urlencoded` string for the post body with just one key-value-pair then to make it work you'd need to post it as `"=10"` and not `"maxRecords=10"`.

To check if this is the issue that's causing the method to fail, I'd temporarily remove GET support leaving it with just POST, and mark the param as FromBody.

Comment: I was not aware of that.  I rewrote it to send as a GET.  Thanks.

Comment: @Jeremy - as long as all you do is really getting information (as opposed to creating resources) it's good to allow just GET to avoid confusion - however, if the POST method was meant to create resources I would separate it into a different method.